# WordPress increases image filesize by at least 10 x

Tags: image, wordpress, resize

when I upload images of about 29kb to my site, their filesize increases to at least 220kb or 287kb.

Im very sure of my facts, Ive worked in photoshop for years, I know how to decrease filesizes significantly, when as I upload and display on front end, and view the image properties in firefox, even download the files and check their size, it has gone from 20KB to about 190KB.

What exactly is the point of WP "crunching" images when uploading, seems like they just crunch more stuff in it.

Anyway. Is there a solution? One that REALLY crunches images on upload? Or even just on display?

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the default image size in WordPress. You can define your own image size to fit your needs using [add_image_size()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).

Code to be added to your functions.php file:

```
 <?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

Add your desired image size and parameters.

Comment: Hi there, no - its not dimensions, its filesize.

Thanks

Comment: Try setting crop to `false` so that the image is not manipulated on Wordpress side.